# Error in meanSquaredError: Shapes 10,1 and 10,2 must match (tensorflow.js)

Tags: javascript, neural-network, tensorflow.js

My code loads data from csv. Then I build a model and pass the data to it. Then I try to train my model with the data.

Right now the above error occurs. As I have very small experience on javascript I do not know where to search. I assume it has something to do with my .batch-call. If I change the line to "}).batch(20);" the error changes to : "Shapes 20,1 and 20,2 must match". In my understanding the batch is set in the "batchsize" parameter in the trainmodel-function. I am at a loss, where my error lies. My dataset has 196 feature-columns and one label-column.

```
  async train(): Promise<any> {
  const csvUrl = '/assets/little.csv';
  const csvDataset = tf.data.csv(
  csvUrl,
  {
    columnConfigs: {
      quit: {
        isLabel: true
      }
    },
    delimiter:','
  });
   const numOfFeatures = (await csvDataset.columnNames()).length -1;      
   console.log(numOfFeatures);
   const flattenedDataset =
   csvDataset
   .map(({xs, ys}: any) =>
     { 
     // Convert xs(features) and ys(labels) from object form (keyed by
     // column name) to array form.
     return {xs:Object.values(xs), ys:Object.values(ys)};
     }).batch(10);    
   console.log(flattenedDataset.toArray());      

   const model = tf.sequential({
     layers: [
       tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [196], units: 100, activation: 'relu'}),
       tf.layers.dense({units: 100, activation: 'relu'}),
       tf.layers.dense({units: 100, activation: 'relu'}),        
       tf.layers.dense({units: 2, activation: 'softmax'}),        
     ]
   }); 
   tfvis.show.modelSummary({name: 'Model Summary'}, model);     
   await trainModel(model, flattenedDataset);
   console.log('Done Training');
   }
}

async function trainModel(model, flattenedDataset) {
  // Prepare the model for training.  
  model.compile({
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(),
    loss: tf.losses.meanSquaredError,
    metrics: ['mse'],
  });

  const batchSize = 32;
  const epochs = 50;

  return await model.fitDataset(flattenedDataset, {
    batchSize,
    epochs,
    shuffle: true,
    callbacks: tfvis.show.fitCallbacks(
      { name: 'Training Performance' },
      ['loss', 'mse'], 
      { height: 200, callbacks: ['onEpochEnd'] }
    )
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last layer has `units:2` whereas only a single column `quit` is set as label.

Either another column is set as label or the number of unit should be 1

Comment: Thank you! That was it!